Why "I thought you would have gone." VS "I thought you went." VS "I thought you would be gone."
A man comes to his house in the evening, turns the lights on in the living room, and sees his wife has been sitting on the couch. He is suprised, and said to her:

I thought you would have gone.

As a non-native speaker, I couldn't understand why you would have gone., because I would have said I thought you went. or I thought you would be gone., both of which would probably be wrong.
For some reason, the structure would have gone reminds me of an IF, conditional sentences, type 3, but there is no such situation here.
So, why is it would have gone? Is it because would have gone reflects the uncertainty of situation in which the man wasn't 100% sure that she went?

Compare:   She will have gone  which expresses expectation on the part of the speaker that she has left.  If backshifted to past tense because the matrix clause is cast in the past tense, I thought, then she will have becomes she would have.   I think she will have gone.  I thought she would have gone.   Expectation is a kind of uncertainty, although some people feel fairly certain when they expect something to happen. But it is less than certain knowledge.

@TimR, thanks that was informative. I didn't think "would have gone" is the past form of "will have gone". That is why I had difficulty in understanding it. Also, it is because at school, the structure "will have gone" is not taught as involving some uncertainty, but rather as a structure for giving information or facts. For example: "When you call me tomorrow, I will have left for Paris." This sentence, for me as a learner, doesn't include any uncertainty. Now I understand it does, and "would have done" and "will have done" are related.

I wouldn't call prediction using will based on knowledge (e.g. of someone's schedule or habit) a declaration of fact, even though pedagogically they may be presented to students as such because in practical circumstances we accept the speaker's  confidence in the prediction as knowing. The train will have left the station before we get there. We should change our plan and take the bus instead. Modals may approach declaration  of fact but they always fall shy of it.

Both "would have gone" and "would be gone" are acceptable. One refers to the action of going, while the other refers to the state after the action.

It's because the speaker was not 100% sure of what she would do or what she did. If he were certain, he would have used: went.

"I thought you went" focuses on the attendance itself, your belief that they did attend, and your surprise on hearing they didn't.
"I thought you would have gone" focuses more on the other person's intention. It implies you thought they wanted to, or were likely to attend, and expresses surprise that they perhaps chose not to.
